# Basic Probability using combinations

Tags: probability, combinations

3. (a) A committee of 5 people is to be chosen from a group of 10 (6 men and 4 women)
   (i) How many committees of 5 members can be chosen from 10 people?
   (ii) How many of the committees from (a) will have exactly 2 women on them?
   a.i) = 252 
   What is a.ii) and how?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  This is a site where you can certainly post questions, but you have to show your attempt in solving them. Homework questions without self-efforts are also strongly discouraged.

Answer (score 2):

There are ${^{10}\mathrm C_{5}}$ ways to choose 5 of 10 people.  That equals $252$.

$${^{10}\mathrm C_{5}} = \dfrac{10!}{5!\,5!} = 252$$

You want to count the ways to choose 2 of 4 women and 3 of 6 men.

$${^{4}\mathrm C_{2}}\cdot{^{6}\mathrm C_{3}} = \dfrac{4!}{2!\,2!}\cdot\dfrac{6!}{3!\,3!} = 120$$

<s>Can you not fill in the boxes?</s>(yes; filled)

---

> Thank you, I can fill in those boxes and that does yield the correct answer, but could you please explain why it is the 4C2 multiplied by the 6C3? –  Lara 6 mins ago - Lara

@Lara You are selecting a committee of $5$ people out of $2$ of $4$ women and $3$ of $6$ men.   There are  $^4 \mathrm C _2$  ways to select the women and, *for each of these*, there are  $^6 \mathrm C _3$  ways to select the men.   So to count the total of ways to perform both these (sequential) tasks we must multiply.

Comment: Thank you, I can fill in those boxes and that does yield the correct answer, but could you please explain why it is the 4C2 multiplied by the 6C3?

Comment: @Lara You are selecting a committee of 2 of 4 women and 3 of 6 men (a committee of size 5).  There are $^4C_2$ ways to select the women and, *for each of these*, there are $^6C_3$ ways to select the men.  So to count the total of ways to perform *both* these (sequential) tasks we must multiply.